# what is the best practice to capture/document javascript function call tree?

Tags: javascript, jquery, visual-studio, cordova, debugging

what is the best practice to capture/document javascript function call tree?

Comment: Welcome on SO. Please have a look at the [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the this tool called [code2flow](https://github.com/scottrogowski/code2flow) which seems to be doing this.

to use install and run:

```
$ code2flow source1.js source2.js -o out.gv
```